# How to use C++ render from WPF project

Tags: c#, c++, vtk

I have a c++ application with my own core and render (I'm using VTK), so I will have a vtkRenderWindow, and I want to put this into a C# WPF project.

I have a managed DLL to use the core from C#, all works (lets say the basic functionality, instantiate managed DLL object, make some calculations, but nothing with render) but I don't know how to put the render into C# Window.

I'm not using C# wrapper, so basically I want to put this render into a C# WPF project, how can I do that?? 
Is there any WPF generic widget to allow to do that??

Thks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only done this in WinForms and for VTK 5.x, there may be a newer solution for WPF and VTK 6 out there.

The vtkFormsWindowControl.dll in VTK allows you to wrap your vtkRenderer so it 
can be displayed in WinForms. 
Here's the VTK documentation with links and examples: http://vtkdotnet.sourceforge.net/Programming.html

You can then host your WinForms control in WPF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit to add version numbers and link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here (like examples and explanation), and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thks for your answer, the links help a lot.

Comment: here I post a full example with WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301087/vtk-render-into-c-sharp/30301203#30301203

Answer (score 2):

After a week searching for some alternatives, all I have to do is past the HWND to C++ class and use the vtkRenderWindow->SetParentId() method to set the vtkRenderWindow as a child of the control I want, of course, I had to create the CLR class etc, but the important here is this method, thks a lot for the answers