# c++/clr vtkInteractor with hwnd

Tags: c#, c++, vtk, hwnd

I successfully implemented a c++ vtk rendererWindow via a clr class into windows Forms, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301203/10325189 . So many thanks for that.
So my question is: is it possible to interact with this windows Form via an vtkInteractor. So lets say I click at anywhere in the hwnd that i get implement functions like: https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Picking/HighlightPickedActor
I have no idea how to start here...
Any help would be great!

[Edit]
okay i think, the question was a little bit too fast asked. I think i will get it. If i am right a have to pick the data (actors) from the c++ native code back to the wpf again... sry...